# What planes of existence does everyone visit while sleeping according to the Great Wheel cosmology?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, sleep, planescape

When someone is sleeping what planes of existence do they visit according to the Great Wheel cosmology in D&D 5e?

I have not found exact information in the rule books about this. Perhaps there are options (good dreams on one plane, nightmares on the other)?

As far as I remember, in one of the previous editions there was a separate plane you went to while dreaming, but what about for D&D 5e?

Is there a mechanic, for example, describing a transition during sleep, a possible death during sleep, or a transition to another person’s sleep that would shed light on this issue?

Maybe there is information compatible with D&D 5th edition in the books about Planescape (since we are dealing with the Great Wheel)?

Please provide references to the sources.

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions here. Do you want to focus on the one in the title, or the others? Please can you [edit] your post to remove the extra question?

Comment: I'm not sure I see multiple questions here. I see one overarching question "what plane of existence do you go to when you sleep" and then some suggestions on angles of attacking that question "are there places where sleep is described? maybe death during sleep?" and a suggestion for a potential source for an answer about the plane question (in Planescape). Am I missing something? (I've also edited this question to try to make this a bit clearer)

Comment: If I can comment this, yes.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I took those angles as having different answers, but that may also not be the case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s entirely possible that dreamers simply *don’t* go anywhere.

Dream has never been a major part of the Great Wheel cosmology—it’s only been mentioned in five publications:

- 2e:

  - *Guide to the Ethereal Plane* where it is very little more than a mention.
  - Ravenloft adventure *The Nightmare Lands* which includes rules for adventuring in dreamscapes. *Guide to the Ethereal Plane* explicitly directs you here if you want to actually go to Dream.
- 3e:

  - *Manual of the Planes*, by far the most detailed version. It still isn’t very.
  - *Dragon* vol. 287, “Dreamlands: Variant Planes of Dream” which doesn’t actually discuss Dream per se, but rather other ways you could implement different kinds of planes for dreaming: inner plane, outer plane, transitive plane, individualized demiplanes for each dreamer, etc.
- 4e:

  - *Manual of the Planes*, which has a few paragraphs on it.

There is no 5th-edition *Manual of the Planes* (yet?), so the most likely place to expect to find information on Dream doesn’t exist. *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* has been the only real source we have so far on planar matters, but it’s devoted pretty heavily to, ya know, “foes,” and Dream doesn’t provide a lot of those, particularly not many that are easily included in a regular campaign.

Notably, 1e and for a good while 2e had the Great Wheel (even if it wasn’t named that yet for 1e) without any mention of Dream, and the 3.5e “revision” of *Manual of the Planes*, *Planar Handbook*, didn’t bother to mention it either. Outside of those five publications, the entire concept never got used in any way, and even if it was supposed to officially exist somehow, it was ignored.

Thus, for the most part, the Great Wheel doesn’t bother with Dream. You can use the write-ups from 2e or 3e or even 4e (though that was the “World Axis” nonsense, not the Great Wheel) if you want, but even those editions themselves mostly elected to simply *not*, and it’s quite likely that 5e is going to follow that pattern—even if it does get mentioned in an eventual *Manual of the Planes* or similar, it’s quite likely to be something that never gets mentioned or leveraged again after that.

#### Dal Quor, Eberron’s Moon/Plane of Dreams

The exception to all this is Eberron, where Dal Quor is a major part of the setting. That said, ***if*** Eberron is connected to the Great Wheel—which is itself debatable—***how*** is completely unknown and a matter of guesswork and speculation. Dal Quor is extremely important to Eberron, but almost certainly irrelevant everywhere else. It is extremely unlikely that dreamers from other worlds go to Dal Quor, unless Dal Quor somehow is Dream (at least in previous editions, the descriptions of the two would have made that quite difficult to reconcile, however).

Comment: The question arose due to the mention in DMG 5e "The Astral Plane is the realm of thought and dream, where visitors travel as disembodied souls to reach the Outer Planes." and the comment "it is believed that intelligent creatures travel to portions of the Astral Plane as they sleep" in the question [What's the difference between the Astral Plane and the Ethereal Plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122009)

Comment: @ben-ben Right, the Astral Plane is the conduit for thoughts, belief, fear, worries, and so on—including the stuff one dreams about—but dreamers don’t go there, it’s just the echoes of their dreams and the thoughts and emotions found in them that ripple across the Astral Plane. The reference to disembodied souls traveling through it to reach the Outer Planes is talking about *astral projection*.

Comment: Finally found it. Manual of the Planes of D&D 3.5 covers The Great Wheel cosmology for this edition. In its chapter "Appendix: Variant Planes and Cosmologies" there is a section "Region of Dreams" (p. 201). Citation: "Into the Region of Dreams come dreamers, whether they will it or not, every time they fall asleep. Their minds take flight to the Region of Dreams. The edges of Dream expand and contract with temporary dreamscapes as dreamers on every plane sleep and wake. Dream would exist even if there were no dreamers, though."

Comment: It's hardly to understand how this can be connected to the Great Wheel, but they try: "Dream Links. The Region of Dreams is coterminous to the Material plane and whatever Transitive, Inner, or Outer Planes you desire. The easiest method of reaching Dream is through the Portal of Sleep... When sleep claims a living mind, the  consciousness  of the sleeper comes to the Region of Dreams, and the dreamer enters into his or her own dreamscape. The body remains on the Material Plane, but the mind wanders as a discrete entity within a dreamscape.".

Comment: Ther is also a mention about the Demiplane of Nightmares on FR wiki (https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Demiplane_of_Nightmares). No idea if it can be used for the Great Wheel (there is no citation for the Great Wheel cosmology). Still it's hard to connect both "Region of Dreams" and "Demiplane of Nightmares" with the Great Wheel. Looks like you mentioned it but it was not clear for me. I was interested in this question because of the character Gannayev-of-Dreams from NWN2.

Comment: @Medix2 Yes, in Eberron, dreamers go to Dal Quor. This doesn't necessarily happen anywhere else (and even if it does, it’s almost-certainly not to Dal Quor).

Comment: @ben-ben Minor correction: *Manual of the Planes* is a 3e book; *Planar Handbook* is the 3.5e book about the planes (though it was meant to expand on *MotP*, not replace it, as far as I know). Anyway, yeah, Dream isn’t really... a thing so much? That’s kind of what I was getting at.

Comment: @ben-ben The Demiplane of Nightmares was also mentioned in Guide to the Ethereal Plane; it's got a couple paragraphs on page 47.

Comment: @KRyan Dreaming got a lot more than a mention in GEP; there's an entire section about the Dreamscape on pages 55-57, including rules for adventuring there.


There's also a long section about (and a segment set within) the Dreamscape in the adventure Something Wild. That adventure is probably the biggest focus on dreaming that Planescape had, and should probably be included in your summary; it also brings in the Dream Hunters, an organization in the Beastlands capable of entering the dreams of others to protect their psyches.

Comment: @Idran Good stuff, I’ll double-check those when I get home.